# How to get GraphQL schema with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, graphql

There's lots of GUI clients like GraphQL Playground, GraphiQl, etc. with ability  of getting GraphQL schema from the URL. How can I get the schema with Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the spec:

> A GraphQL server supports introspection over its schema. This schema is queried using GraphQL itself, creating a powerful platform for tool‐building... The schema introspection system is accessible from the meta‐fields __schema and __type which are accessible from the type of the root of a query operation.

Tools like GraphQL Playground and GraphiQL utilize introspection to get information about a schema. You don't need any additional tools or libraries to make an introspection query -- since it's just a GraphQL query, you'll make the request the same way you make any other request to the endpoint (using `requests` for example).

Here's a complete introspection query from `graphql-core`:

```
introspection_query = """
  query IntrospectionQuery {
    __schema {
      queryType { name }
      mutationType { name }
      subscriptionType { name }
      types {
        ...FullType
      }
      directives {
        name
        description
        locations
        args {
          ...InputValue
        }
      }
    }
  }
  fragment FullType on __Type {
    kind
    name
    description
    fields(includeDeprecated: true) {
      name
      description
      args {
        ...InputValue
      }
      type {
        ...TypeRef
      }
      isDeprecated
      deprecationReason
    }
    inputFields {
      ...InputValue
    }
    interfaces {
      ...TypeRef
    }
    enumValues(includeDeprecated: true) {
      name
      description
      isDeprecated
      deprecationReason
    }
    possibleTypes {
      ...TypeRef
    }
  }
  fragment InputValue on __InputValue {
    name
    description
    type { ...TypeRef }
    defaultValue
  }
  fragment TypeRef on __Type {
    kind
    name
    ofType {
      kind
      name
      ofType {
        kind
        name
        ofType {
          kind
          name
          ofType {
            kind
            name
            ofType {
              kind
              name
              ofType {
                kind
                name
                ofType {
                  kind
                  name
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
"""
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this query works and returns all the fields!

Answer (score 1):

The `graphql-core` has utilities to get you the query, and convert the query result. Here is an example snippet that print the resulting schema in sdl:

```
from graphqlclient import GraphQLClient
from pprint import PrettyPrinter
from graphql import get_introspection_query, build_client_schema, print_schema

def main():
    pp = PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    client = GraphQLClient('http://swapi.graph.cool/')
    query_intros = get_introspection_query(descriptions=True)
    intros_result = client.execute(query_intros, variables=None, operationName=None)
    client_schema = build_client_schema(intros_result.get('data', None))
    sdl = print_schema(client_schema)
    print(sdl)
    pp.pprint(sdl)
```

I was looking for the same and found the above in the end.

Comment: This gives me the following error: `TypeError: execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'operationName'`

Comment: Ok. Just take out the "operationName=None" from the call. It works on "https://graphql.org/swapi-graphql/". It works with the intro_result. But the next line creating schema will fail, need to replace "data" element with a valid one. The environment: python 3.8, graphql-core 3.0.3, graphqlclient 0.2.4, urllib3 1.25.8. You can pick a public api from https://github.com/APIs-guru/graphql-apis

Comment: Got method not allowed. Tried a few other links, each gives a different error. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a json file with your schema.

```
import json

introspection_dict = your_schema_object.introspect()

# Or save the schema into some file
with open("schema.json", "w") as fp:
    json.dump(introspection_dict, fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sqglc library](https://sgqlc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sgqlc.introspection.html), introspection module.

**1. Creates a json schema file:**

```
python3 -m sgqlc.introspection --exclude-deprecated --include-description ****-H "Authorization: Bearer {TOKEN}" http://yourgrapqlservice.com schema.json
```

--exclude-deprecated
If given, will exclude deprecated fields and enumeration values.

Default: False

--exclude-description
If given, will exclude description (documentation).

**2. Converts the schema to .py format if needed:**

```
sgqlc-codegen schema schema1.json schema.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem until I came across the answer in the python graphql repo, you can use this code snippet example to get the schema and save it in a .json file

```
async def get_graphql_schema(endpoint, api_key):
    headers = {"X-API-KEY": api_key}
    transport = AIOHTTPTransport(url=endpoint, headers=headers)
    async with Client(transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=True) as session:
        query_intros = get_introspection_query(descriptions=True)
        query = gql(query_intros)
        intros_result = await session.execute(query)
        schema = build_client_schema(intros_result)
        return schema

def save_schema_to_json(schema):
    schema_dict = introspection_from_schema(schema)
    output_file = 'schema.json'
    with open(output_file, 'w') as json_file:
        dump(schema_dict, json_file, indent=2)

schema = asyncio.run(get_graphql_schema(env_dev['url'], env_dev['key']))
save_schema_to_json(schema)
```

What you are looking for is `introspection_from_schema()` and I quote its documentation in the source code :

> Build an IntrospectionQuery from a GraphQLSchema
>
> IntrospectionQuery is useful for utilities that care about type and
> field
> relationships, but do not need to traverse through those relationships.
>
> This is the inverse of build_client_schema. The primary use case is
> outside of the
> server context, for instance when doing schema comparisons.